# f.read() doesn't read nothing in the 2nd iteration of a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, sha256, hmac

I am trying to create a script that reads files from a directory and create a .txt file that maps the name of the file with its hash code (SHA256).

These are the imports and global variable declarations:

```
import os
from unicodedata import name
import hashlib

hashsha = hashlib.sha256()
directorio_config = r"C:\Users\santi\Documents\wsp_py\PA1\config"
directorio = r"C:\Users\santi\Documents\wsp_py\PA1\ficheros"
aux = dict()
BUF_SIZE = 65536  # lets read stuff in 64kb chunks!
```

I have two functions:

```
def get_ficheros(directorio, directorio_config):
    with os.scandir(directorio) as ficheros:
        for elemento in ficheros:
            if elemento.is_file():
                nombre_fichero = elemento.name
                ruta = directorio + "\\" + nombre_fichero
                hash_code = hash_file(ruta)
                aux[elemento.name] = hash_code
            else:
                newdir = directorio + "\\" + elemento.name
                get_ficheros(newdir, directorio_config)
        return aux
```

This one is suposed to read the files from a directory and put them in a dictionary where the value is the hash calculated by the `hash_file` function.
Here it is:

```
def hash_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            hashsha.update(data)
        f.close()    

return hashsha.hexdigest()
```

This code works properly untill the first iteration. In the second iteration, `f.read()` reads `b''` and it is stored in the variable "data" instead the second file hash code as it is expected.
I have no idea why this happens. Any help is appriciated. Thnks

Comment: The file was apparently no more than 65536 bytes long.  The first `.read()` read the entire file, the second iteration of the loop found nothing further to read.  This is exactly how the code should work, the only problem I see is that you need to create a new `hashlib.sha256()` object for each file.

Comment: Since you're recursively walking through the directory structure, I would recommend trying os.walk().

Comment: You don't need `f.close()` when you use `with` to open the file.